# Flutter project build failed

Tags: flutter

I am using the location plugin in my project. but the build has failed!

Here is the snapshot of the build error. What could be the reason for the build fail?

```
Building plugin location...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done 16.1s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin location_web...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done 2.9s

Task :assembleAarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :parseReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE

Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

Task :mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
Task :processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
Task :stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Task :transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
17 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 16 up-to-date

/home/saeedhpro/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_web-1.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location_web/LocationWebPlugin.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
^
symbol: class NonNull
location: package androidx.annotation
/home/saeedhpro/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_web-1.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location_web/LocationWebPlugin.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
public void onAttachedToEngine(@nonnull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) { }
^
symbol: class NonNull
location: class LocationWebPlugin
/home/saeedhpro/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location_web-1.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/lyokone/location_web/LocationWebPlugin.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
public void onDetachedFromEngine(@nonnull FlutterPluginBinding binding) { }
^
symbol: class NonNull
location: class LocationWebPlugin
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

The plugin location_web could not be built due to the issue above.

Output of flutter doctor:

```
flutter doctor -v:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 1.17.2 at /home/saeedhpro/other/softwares/flutter
• Framework revision 5f21edf8b6 (6 days ago), 2020-05-28 12:44:12 -0700
• Engine revision b851c71829
• Dart version 2.8.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at /home/saeedhpro/Android/Sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = /home/saeedhpro/Android/Sdk
• Java binary at: /softwares/android-studio/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at /softwares/android-studio
• Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
```

[✓] Proxy Configuration
• HTTP_PROXY is set
• NO_PROXY is .github.com,.getcomposer.org,.laravel.com,.packagist.org,.npmjs.org,localhost,127.0.0.1,.yarnpkg.com,https://production.cloudflare.docker.com
• NO_PROXY contains 127.0.0.1
• NO_PROXY contains localhost

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• SM J701F • 5200acc94e1cb43d • android-arm • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!

Comment: did you try doing pub get and build the project again?

Comment: yes. on every time!